# get all elements by tag name and invoke them in loop (C# webbrowser)

Tags: c#, winforms

```
foreach(HTMLElement he in webBrowser.getElementByTagName("img"))
{
    if(he.getAttribute("id").Contains("img"))
        he.InvokeMember("click");
    while(webBrowser.IsBusy)
        Application.DoEvents;
}
```

this is code section in which I have problem.
in first iteration htmlelement is invoked and corresponding page is loaded successfully but on invoking of second element it gives the following error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

(Each element in loop is link to other page)

Comment: `but on invoking of second element it gives error`, what error, please update your post to include this. Also `Application.DoEvents`, why the need for this, it can have some consequences and more than likely you need to remove it.

Comment: Post the error message, please.

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

Comment: @Sakoon Is this inside a frame by chance?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Application.DoEvents is used to wait for webpage to load.

Comment: @Sakoon I know, but you don't and shouldn't, not at least that way. Look into the `DocumentCompleted Event` you can subscribe to.

Comment: Can you post the actual source to the page? If it's contained in a frame, you would more than likely get that access is denied, the reason is because its trying to prevent a cross frame scripting security issue.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ actually I want to search products from whole website. So First load main page . that page has 15 products and I want to navigate to all those 15 products How can I do this?

Comment: @Sakoon does the company provide an API, is so use it. If not, you need to look into a web scraping/parsing library. Also, you didn't provide the html (webpage source) I asked so I can inspect it, without it I can't help.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ https://www.microcenter.com/category/4294967292,4294819353/apple-desktops this is the webpage and there is no api